# The ui-datepicker-year in WooCommerce WordPress only showing 20 years

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**I need to update the function.php file so that its showing 99 years not just 20 years, I am running Bizberg theme

Tried this, and it failed to give me an extended range, the issues is the scroll bar still only allows 20 years, I need99**

```
function extend_date_of_birth_range() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            var startYear = currentYear - 99;
            var endYear = currentYear - 10;

            // Replace "billing_date_of_birth" with the ID or name of your date of birth field
            $('#billing_date_of_birth').datepicker('option', {
                yearRange: startYear + ':' + endYear
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'extend_date_of_birth_range');
```

Comment: So what have you done so far to try and debut the issue? Checked the browser console for errors? Verified the code actually executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function in function.php file, hope this will help

```
<?php 
function extend_date_of_birth_range() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            var startYear = currentYear - 99;
            var endYear = currentYear - 10;
            var dateRange = '"'+startYear+' : '+endYear+'"';

            // Replace "billing_date_of_birth" with the ID or name of your date of birth field
            $('#billing_date_of_birth').datepicker('option', {
                yearRange: dateRange
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'extend_date_of_birth_range');
?>
```

Comment: You are not allowed to make multiple answers on a question, instead please update your initial answer and delete this one…

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
var dateRange = '"'+startYear+' : '+endYear+'"';
```

and put the "dateRange" variable as below:

```
// Replace "billing_date_of_birth" with the ID or name of your date of birth field
$('#billing_date_of_birth').datepicker('option', {
     yearRange: dateRange
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am looking for something I can add to the funtion.php file in the theme

Comment: then you can use  `add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');` action hook.. which will add the script in footer